# Impact of spurious regressors on out of sample prediction error

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, mean-square-error

The true DGP is 
\begin{equation}
y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_k x_k +\epsilon, \quad \epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
but we instead estimate

\begin{equation}
y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_k x_k + \dots + \alpha_{k'} x_{k'} \epsilon, \quad \epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)\label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
where $k'>k$. The observations are fixed design.

Is it true that the standard error of the out of sample prediction of the estimated function (with spurious regressors) at some fixed $(x_1^*, \dots, x_{k'}^*)$ is (weakly) greater than the standard error of the out of sample prediction at $(x_1^*, \dots, x_k^*)$ using the correctly specified model? If so, how can I prove this?

Comment: You've got a row vector $x_i \in \mathbb R^{K_1}$, so $x_i = (x_{i,1}, \ldots, x_{i,K_1})$, and similarly $z_i = (z_{i,1}, \ldots, z_{i,K_2})$. How can you find a linear combination of a vector in $\mathbb R^{K_1}$ and one in $\mathbb R^{K_2}$ unless $K_1=K_2$?  If if they're equal, why bother with the notations $K_1,K_2$ rather than saying $x_i, z_i \in \mathbb R^K$?  Assuming they are equal, I don't know that I've seen a model like this before.  I half-way wonder if you meant simply $x_i\in\mathbb R$ so that $x\in\mathbb R^N$. $\qquad$

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the true model is $y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_k x_k$ and the misspecified model is $y_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1x_1 + \dots + \alpha_k x_k + \alpha_{k+1}x_{k+1} + \dots + \alpha_{k'} x_{k'}$ for some $k'>k$. I can rewrite above to make this clearer.

Comment: After your recent edit, it still looks as if you're trying to take a linear combination of two vectors that don't have equal numbers of components. $\qquad$

Comment: Edited again -- let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: Looks ok now.  Maybe I can work out the answer by doing some algebra, but maybe someone else knows the answer without doing that. $\qquad$

Comment: For the "unspecified" model - the noise term $\epsilon$ is multiplicative?